# Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'F:\Projects\Table42\trunk\app\libs\appsee.jar'

Tags: android

Getting this error on run time for the application but compilation is succesfully.

**ERROR**

> Error:Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'classpath' during up-to-date check.> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'F:\Projects\Table42\trunk\app\libs\appsee.jar'.

my gradle ::

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.imate.android'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 15
        versionName "1.14"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG_MODE", "false"
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG_MODE", "true"
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.20.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    compile files('libs/appsee.jar')
    compile files('libs/AF-Android-SDK-v2.3.1.18.jar')
    compile('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'

    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.edmodo:rangebar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava-collections:r03'
    compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    compile 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'

    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.4.+'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.1') {
        transitive = false
    }

    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:4.0.1'
    compile "com.github.miguelbcr:RxPaparazzo:0.5.2-2.x"

    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.4'
    compile 'org.honorato.multistatetogglebutton:multistatetogglebutton:0.2.2'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$rootProject.ext.supportAnnotationsversion"

    // Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:$rootProject.ext.runnerVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:$rootProject.ext.rulesVersion"

    // Espresso UI Testing dependencies.
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'

    //geofire
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'

    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'

    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.+'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.ratty3697:android-smart-animation-library:1.6'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(path: ':firebase')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'**
```

Comment: @Vishal Vaishnav any idea for above issue.